# CSS: 3-columns layout into 2-columns

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I have a layout with 3 columns:

```
----------------------------------
|left     |middle      |right    |
----------------------------------
```

And it is fine, but I'd like to have 2 columns on smaller screens:

```
---------------------
|left     |right    |
---------------------
|middle             |
---------------------
```

It is important for the second row to be 100% wide.

Is it possible to do so only with CSS?

My HTML markup:

```
<article class="item">
    <div class="item-name">left</div>
    <div class="item-ingredients">middle</div>             
    <div class="item-prices">
        <div class="item-price">right1</div>                    
        <div class="item-price">right2</div>                    
        <div class="item-price">right3</div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Comment: if question Is it possible to do so only with CSS? yes that is posible using css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use media queries, this [link](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) help you understand about media queries

html

```
<article class="item">
    <div class="item-name">left</div>           
    <div class="item-prices">
        <div class="item-price">right1</div>                    
        <div class="item-price">right2</div>                    
        <div class="item-price">right3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-ingredients">middle</div>  
</article>
```

css

```
.item {float:left; width:100%}
.item div {
    float:left;
    width:33.3%;
    background-color:#555;
}
.item div div {width:33%}
.item div.item-ingredients {background-color:blue}
.item div.item-prices {float:right}

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .item div.item-ingredients{
        width:100%;
    }
    .item div {width:50%}
}
```

by the way don't forget to put this before end `tag` of you `head`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

update [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MsYdJ/24/)

note:scroll the fiddle to see the effect

hope this help you....

Comment: Yours and @BharatChodvadiya solutions work, but maybe I did not stress this enough: I'd like the "item-ingredients" column to pop into the second row, while both yours answers put "item-prices" there.

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I wanted:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this html and css.

```
<article class="item">
 <div class="first" style="width:100%;">
   <div class="item-name" style="width:50%; float: left;">left</div>
   <div class="item-ingredients" style="width:50%; float: left;">right</div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="item-prices" style="width:100%;">middle</div>
</article>
```

Hope it helps to you.